# Star "*" in registry key path

Tags: powershell, registry

What is the correct syntax to delete registry keys when an asterisk is in the middle ot the registiry path, like this:

```
"Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shellex\
ContextMenuHandlers\SimpleShlExt\{45203D3B-3D73-4497-8AFE-D29950AC6C55}"
```

Comment: `Remove-Item -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\SimpleShlExt{45203D3B-3D73-4497-8AFE-D29950AC6C55}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete a registry key using [Remove-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-6). If you include no parameters when running `Remove-Item`, your path value will automatically be assigned to the `-Path` parameter. The `-Path` parameter accepts [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-6), which includes `*`. To treat wildcard characters as literals, you can use the `-LiteralPath` parameter instead.

```
Remove-Item -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\SimpleShlExt{45203D3B-3D73-4497-8AFE-D29950AC6C55}'
```

The different registry hives are automatically mapped as `PSDriveInfo` objects in your session. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` has the drive name `HKLM`. You interact with that drive just like any other mapped drive, i.e. where you could use `"C:\Path"`, you could potentially use the syntax `"HKLM:\Path"`.